# How do I make my character stop after colliding

Tags: pygame, sprite, collision

my character should just stop after hitting a sprite group but I don't know how.
Collision works perfectly.

I tried to set the velocity to null but then I can't move my character anymore.
hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks in advance

> ```
> def update(self):
>     self.animate()
>     self.x += self.velx
>     self.y += self.vely
>     BATTLE.fight += round(BATTLE.fightcount * 0.9)
> ```
>
> hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(PLAYER, all_sprites, False)

```
if hit:
    if PLAYER.x >= b.rect.x:
       PLAYER.x = b.rect.x - 17
    elif PLAYER.x <= b.rect.x:
        PLAYER.x = b.rect.x + 15
    elif PLAYER.y <= b.rect.y:
        PLAYER.y = b.rect.y +10
    elif PLAYER.y >= b.rect.y:
        PLAYER.y = b.rect.y -10
```

> ```
> for event in pygame.event.get():
>     if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
>         setup_gfx.done = True
>         sys.exit()
>     if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
>         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
>             BATTLE.fightcount +=1
>             PLAYER.velx -= 1
>             PLAYER.current_frame += 1
>         if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
>             BATTLE.fightcount += 1
>             PLAYER.velx += 1
>             PLAYER.current_frame += 1
>         if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
>             BATTLE.fightcount +=1
>             PLAYER.vely -= 1
>             PLAYER.current_frame += 1
>         if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
>             BATTLE.fightcount +=1          
>             PLAYER.vely += 1
>             PLAYER.current_frame += 1
> ```

Comment: Can you tell us what is a velocity in your case? Is it yours variable or one provided by the pygame library?

Comment: sorry, Velocity is the number of pixel which my character goes after hitting left, right, up or down. it's added to my x-coordinate.

Comment: so there is no point of setting it to null. What you can do is take the size of obstacle, and on collision it would mean you have to make character adjust its position so its not intersecting with the obstacle. ex. block has size 10x10 and position on screen 100, 100. Then your character (assume point to simplify) going into 101, 100 must be adjusted to 100, 100. btw can't this be handled by pygame somehow?

Comment: I think this link might be helpful: https://www.pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html

Comment: I had the same thought but the issue is that the obstacle is in the middle of the area so it has two y coordinates and two x coordinates.

Comment: I have sprite groups because there are several objects where my character has to stop and not only one. Collide rect ist just for two rects I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed it and it works perfectly. So here is the appropriate code.

"""

```
    hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(PLAYER, all_sprites, False)

    for collision in hit:
        if PLAYER.velx > 0:
            PLAYER.velx = 0
            PLAYER.x -= 10
        elif PLAYER.velx < 0:
            PLAYER.velx = 0
            PLAYER.x += 10
    for collision in hit:
        if PLAYER.vely > 0:
            PLAYER.vely = 0
            PLAYER.y -= 10
        elif PLAYER.vely < 0:
            PLAYER.vely = 0
            PLAYER.y += 10
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, pushing an arrow key increases the player's velocity.  Each call to `Player.update()` moves the player by `Player.velx` and `Player.vely` pixels.  So setting the `velx` and `vely` velocity to `0` is enough to stop the player movement.

```
class Player( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    ...
    def stop( self ):
        self.velx = 0
        self.vely = 0
```

However, I suspect that there's an additional problem in that the player sprite is getting "hung up" on whatever it has collided with.  This becomes a bigger problem when the sprite is moving by larger amounts of pixels each time.  At one update-cycle the player has not collided, but the very next update, it could be 5 pixels inside a platform (or whatever).  What happens on collision - the velocity is reduced to zero, but the player is "stuck" on the object.

The way around this is to use the amount/direction of the last "step" (`vel` pixels in this case), and use it to stop the player at the *edge* of the obstacle, rather than overlapping it.

Comment: like you said if he has already collided, I can't move my character anymore. I set it to null before and this isn't a good idea.